# Select with two counts on same column

Tags: sql, mysql, select, group-by

I have two select queries:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, count(DISTINCT ip) 
FROM table_name WHERE field = 1 GROUP BY month
```

and

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, count(DISTINCT ip) 
FROM table_name WHERE field = 2 GROUP BY month
```

how can I write one query to select

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, 
       count(DISTINCT ip) [ for field = 1], 
       count(DISTINCT ip) [ for field = 2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, 
       count(DISTINCT case when field = 1 then ip end) as f1,
       count(DISTINCT case when field = 2 then ip end) as f2
FROM table_name 
WHERE field in (1,2)
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Thank I didn't know about `case when .. then` systax.